# Free program to view .sequencediagram files

Tags: visual-studio-2010, reverse-engineering, visio, sequence-diagram

Is there a free program to view ".sequencediagram" files generated by VS2010 Ultimate?  I have generated some and want to share them with my team, but do not want to copy and paste all of them into images files.

Answer (score 1):

There is not a free tool to view .sequencediagram files, but you can use the extensibility within VS Ultimate to export the diagram as an image.  See http://blogs.msdn.com/b/camerons/archive/2010/03/08/save-a-diagram-to-image-file.aspx

Comment: On trying to open a .sequencediagram file in Visio 2010 it showed the message "Visio cannot open the file because it's not a Visio file or it has become corrupted"